# How to remove null values from a csv? Python + Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to remove null values in a csv. I am using `dropna`, but when I run I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'pandas' module does not have 'dropna' attribute`

My code is this:

```
pd.read_csv('priv/products.csv', sep=',')
pd.dropna(inplace=True)
print(pd)
```

Comment: `df.dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: is that your real code or did you just make some errors for the MWE? Because you probably should assign some variable to your csv. e.g. `products = pd.read_csv(…)` and then do `products.dropna…`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('priv/products.csv', sep=',')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove null values in a csv. First you need to import the Pandas library because we are using the object 'pd' of Pandas to drop null values from the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
```

After importing the library, you need to know how many null values you have in your dataframe.

```
df.isnull().any()
missing_values = ['NONE', 'None', 'none', 'NAN', 'Nan', 'nan', 'NA', 'Na', 'na']
df = pd.read_csv('.priv/products.csv', na_values = missing_values)
df.isnull().sum()
```

After all of this you need to run the

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

All the null values will be dropped permanently from your dataframe. I hope this will help with your problem.